# ¿Cómo insertar valores char en una matriz 2D?

Tags: c++, matrices, dev-c++, matriz

El ejercicio que nos dejó el profesor fue "Realicen una matriz[x][y] donde al imprimirla se obtengan palabras enteras como resultado". El gran problema de esto es que el profesor no nos ha dado esta clase debido a problemas internos del salón, así que tengo que buscar esto por mi cuenta. He buscado varias cosas sobre matrices 2D y no encuentro cómo asignar valores desde el inicio. Esto fue lo que hice:

```
int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int b[5] = {0, 15, 20, 30, 45};
char c[5][30];

c[0] = {Objeto};
c[1] = {Cosa};
c[2] = {Utensilio};

int i, j;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cout<<" "<<a[i];
    cout<<"\t\t "<<b[i];
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout<<" \t\t"<<c[i][j]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Los arreglos "a" y "b" imprime sin problema, pero mi duda es cómo puedo asignar los valores a la matriz "c", y a su vez cómo se imprime correctamente? Intenté también asignar el valor desde c[0][0], luego c[1][0] y así, pero según entiendo eso lo que hace es tratar de asignar la palabra entera a UNA sola casilla. Soy prácticamente nuevo en todo esto, llevo Programación únicamente un semestre ):

Answer (score 0):

Con esta declaración:

```
char c[5][30];
```

Estás creando una matriz llamada `c` que almacena un único `char` en cada posición.

Los caracteres se almacenan en variables de tipo `char`, mientras que las cadenas de caracteres se almacenan en arrays de char `char[]`, punteros a char `char*` o instancias de `std::string`.

Es decir, si quieres que cada posición de tu array 2D pueda almacenar una cadena de caracteres, necesitas dar una dimensión más al array:

```
char c[5][30][200];
//     ~  ~~  ~~~
//     1   2   3
```

Donde:

1. Primera dimensión del array (x)
2. Segunda dimensión del array (y)
3. Número de caracteres que puedes almacenar en cualquier posición c[x][y]

Aunque, como te he dicho, también podrías usar `std::string`:

```
std::string c[5][30];
```

Esta otra opción funciona sin una tercera dimensión porque la clase `std::string` ya se encarga por si misma de gestionar una cadena de caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré lo que estaba buscando!

Al final simplemente era de la misma manera que había declarado inicialmente la matriz, pero para asignar valores desde un inicio tenía que haber separado por comas:

```
char c[3][30] = {"Objeto", "Cosa", "Utensilio"}
```

Así mismo, la manera que encontré para imprimir estos 3 valores fue de la siguiente manera:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cout<<" "<<c[i]<<endl;
}
```

No tiene que ponerse 2 dimensiones como pensé, únicamente la primera que es la posición donde inicia cada palabra (En 0 está la primera, 1 la segunda, etc etc)